# Is there any way to open the running of the code in a 'jsfiddle' in full-screen?

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

Is there any way to open the running of the code in a 'jsfiddle' in full-screen?

I mean the bit in red here:

[image]

Comment: CVers - this is on-topic as it's asking about functionality in a tool "primarily used for programming" (JSFiddle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can. Save the code and append /show to the url

```
Example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/q7oam39t/show
```

Comment: not working anymore

Comment: it is working @JohannesPertl

Comment: huh weird, I could swear yesterday it was not. Oh well, thanks :)